# Bad production of 2.5.4.5 oid into X509IssuerName, change proposal

Tags: x509certificate, xades4j

I noticed that durnig a xades signature with xades4j the element X509IssuerName presents a bad formatted serialnumber issuer value, it shows a PrintableString Hex encoded, i search into xades4j code and i found that the problem is into the DataGenBaseCertRefs class, if you set

cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getName(X500Principal.RFC1779)

into the generate method you can resolve this problem and procuce an issuer value from this:

2.5.4.5=#130b3037393435323131303036

to this

OID.2.5.4.5=07945211006

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that change is correct. XML-DSIG states that [RFC 4514](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4514.txt) should be used when encoding the distinguished names. Regarding the attribute type, on that RFC one reads:

> If the AttributeType is defined to have a short name (...) that short name, a *descr*, is used.  Otherwise the AttributeType is encoded as the **dotted-decimal encoding, a *numericoid*,** of its OBJECT IDENTIFIER.

In turn, *numericoid* is defined on [RFC 4512](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4512.txt) as follows:

> numericoid = number 1*( DOT number )

Regarding the attribute value, one reads:

> If the AttributeType is of the dotted-decimal form, the AttributeValue is represented by **an number sign ('#' U+0023) character** followed by the hexadecimal encoding of each of the octets of the BER e ncoding of the X.500 AttributeValue.

My understanding is that, since a short name was not known, the hex value should be used. What do you think?

This actually makes me realize that xades4j is using RFC 2253, since [it is the default on getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/x500/X500Principal.html#getName()).

- Are you also including a `X509IssuerSerial` element on `KeyInfo/X509Data`? Is that one different from the cert ref?
- Can you send me, on another channel, a certificate with those characteristics for tests?

Comment: Apache Santuario is also using the same approach, so my first question is answered. See here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/santuario/xml-security-java/tags/xmlsec-1.5.7/src/main/java/org/apache/xml/security/keys/content/x509/XMLX509IssuerSerial.java?view=markup

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i cannot send you the certificate that i used, but it is a simple certificate issued by a certification authority that contains 2.5.4.5 - id-at-serialNumber on the issuer.